# Parse JSON as easily as XML can be in Python 3

Tags: xml, json, python-3.x

In Python 3 it is easy to find a given tag in an XML file via etree.

Using JSON, I've found there isn't a function to do that. Is there a library that does so efficiently? Is it worth my time to have a tree constructed from some JSON?

I'm having to use `woeid = data["places"]["place"][0]["woeid"]` where with XML I could simply use `tree.findall("\\woeid")`, though I'm assuming there's a significant overhead for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

[jsonpath](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath) is an XPath for JSON.